# iOS, Safari on tap, black outline around elements

Tags: ios7, mobile-safari

We are facing an... interesting issue. This is specifically happening on iOS 7 in Safari when you tap on an anchor or input element.

[image: issue]

Currently we have "-webkit-tap-highlight-color" for iOS < 7 to disable the gray box around the link on tap. We also want to remove this border in iOS 7. Setting outline to 0 or none doesn't get rid of it either.

There doesn't appear to be anything mentioned in the new Safari in 
[Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html).

The site is househappy.org

Anyone dealt with this yet? Ideas, suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: This appears to have something to do with position: relative on a clickable element.

Answer (score -1):

This was happening to me and it had to do with the meta tag allowing zoom

Applying a meta tag to disable zoom solved my problem (user-scalable = no)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```